# Yii2 gridview pagination shows same values

Tags: yii2, yii2-grid

I have the following code in modelsearch for gridview display of data.

```
public function search($params )
    {
    $tech=array(22,24,25,29);
        $query=(new \yii\db\Query())-> select(['tbl_ticket.*',
            'tbl_assignment.ticket_id',
            'tbl_assignment.tech_id',
            'tbl_assignment.date_time',
            'tbl_techs.f_name',
            'tbl_techs.loc',
            'tbl_techs.attachment',
            'tbl_techs.dep',
            'tbl_techs.sec']);
        $query->from('tbl_ticket');

        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'tbl_assignment', 'tbl_assignment.ticket_id = tbl_ticket.id');
        $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'tbl_techs', 'tbl_techs.id = tbl_assignment.tech_id');

        $query->where(['tbl_assignment.id' => $tech]);
        $para = isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : $_GET['email'];
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 5,
                'params'=>array('email' => $para)
            ],
        ]);
        $query->andWhere(['tbl_ticket.hd_user_email' => $para]);

        if (! ($this->load($params ) && $this->validate())) {

            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->andFilterWhere(array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'ticket_id' => $this->ticket_id,
            'tech_id' => $this->tech_id,
            'date_time' => $this->date_time,
        ));
        return $dataProvider;

    }
```

It shows the gridview, but when pagination is clicked, it shows same data.
What causes this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `$params` represent  your criteria conditions. 
when you click on the next page these conditions are sent to your search function. So in your code you have to actually load these `$params`  to your search model.ie:

```
    ....     
   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);
   ....
```

You'll also have to remove `$tech=array(22,24,25,29)`and have it in your controller ie:

```
$yourDataProvider = $yourSearchModel->search([$yourSearchModel->formName() => ['tbl_assignment.id' => $tech]])
```

Comment: No change after this

Comment: also $this->load($params); is loaded in  if (! ($this->load($params ) && $this->validate())) {